# GO TO statements- Fortran to Matlab

Tags: matlab, fortran

I have been trying really hard to convert this grid search code from Fortran to Matlab, however I am not able to properly incorporate the GO TO statements (I am trying to use while loops but I think I need something else for them end the search).  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
vmax    = -1.0E+15           
amax_G  = -1

askipR  = REAL(ac_max - ac_min)/REAL(intA)

askip   = CEILING(askipR)


DO acc0 = 1,intA+1  

acc = ac_min + askipR * (acc0-1)  

    cons = ( x1 - grida2(acc) ) / onetauc

    IF (cons<0.0) GOTO 102

    vtemp = utilR(cons) + one_sv * utilB(acc)

    IF (vtemp>vmax) THEN      
        vmax = vtemp
        amax_G = acc
    ELSE
        GOTO 102
    ENDIF

ENDDO ! acc0


102 continue

IF (askip<2) GO TO 109

askip = askip/2

IF (amax_G>ac_min) THEN  

    acc = amax_G - askip
    cons = ( x1 - grida2(acc) ) / onetauc

    IF (cons<0.0) PRINT *,'WARNING: NEGATIVE CONS @ ASEARCH_Rx'

    vtemp = utilR(cons) + one_sv * utilB(acc)

    IF (vtemp>vmax) THEN
        vmax   = vtemp
        amax_G = acc
        GOTO 102
    ENDIF

ENDIF 


IF (amax_G < ac_max) THEN  

    acc  = amax_G + askip
    cons = ( x1 - grida2(acc) ) / onetauc

    IF (cons<0.0) GO TO 102

    vtemp = utilR(cons) + one_sv * utilB(acc)

    IF (vtemp>vmax) THEN
        vmax = vtemp
        amax_G = acc
    ENDIF

ENDIF 

GOTO 102

109 CONTINUE

vfunR(jc,ac,sc)   = vmax    ! jc=Nj

afunR_G(jc,ac,sc) = amax_G  ! jc=Nj
```

Comment: To break a loop, you want `break`

Comment: @chw21the question is going FROM fortran TO matlab... and matlab definitely uses `break`...

Comment: @chw21 this is not a question about writing Fortran code....

Comment: My bad, I thought he wanted to write Fortran.

Comment: If I use break inside the if statement (in Matlab) would that break the remaining of a while loop?

Comment: You can use `continue` in MATLAB to just go to the next loop iteration, less severe than `break`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two types of control-flow implemented with your GOTO statement:

**Type 1: breaking out of a loop**

The GOTO statement is used to break out of the DO-loop:

```pascal
    DO acc0 = 1,intA+1  
        ! some code
        IF (cons<0.0) GOTO 102
        ! some more code
    END DO
102 continue
```

As you notice, if `cons < 0.0` the GOTO statement states to move to label 102 which is located just outside of the DO-loop. In matlab is nothing more than a simple `break` in a for-loop:

```
for acc0=1:intA+1
  % some matlab code
  if (cons < 0.0)
    break
  end
  % some more matlab code
end
```

**Type 2: creating a loop**

While the loop is not explicitly written, the following code creates something that can be translated as a while loop:

```pascal
    ! This is the start of the loop
102 continue
    ! This is the condition to exit the loop <<==
    IF (askip<2) GO TO 109
    ! stuff
    ! This is a condition to restart the loop    <<==
    IF (vtemp>vmax) THEN
         vmax   = vtemp
         amax_G = acc
         GOTO 102
    ENDIF
    ! stuff
    ! This is another condition to restart the loop   <<==
    IF (cons<0.0) GO TO 102
    ! stuff
    ! This is the end of the loop, asked to restart it  <<==
    GOTO 102
    ! This is outside of the loop
109 CONTINUE
```

In the end, you translate this as:

```
while (askip >=2)
   % stuff
   if (vtemp > vmax)
        vmax = vtemp
        amax_G = acc
        continue
   end
   % stuff
   if (cons < 0.0)
      continue
   end
   % stuff
end
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: Some other resources: If you have more fortran code to convert to matlab code in the future, try f2matlab. F2matlab expects fortran code to be in f90 format (with no goto's), so use Alan Miller's to_f90 or Mike Metcalf's convert.f90 to get the code into f90 format, and Alfasoft's plusfort spag to get rid of around 70% of the goto's. If there are too many goto's remaining to refactor by hand, my remgoto can refactor the rest.

Comment: DO lc = 1,Nl 
 !some code 1
    
 IF (x0.le.0.0) GOTO 3003 
 
 !some code 2     

 3003 CONTINUE

ENDDO ! lc

In the above code the continue statement is inside the do loop. Does the GOTO then mean that it's asking to exit the do loop? So I can similarly use break in matlab?

for lc = 1:Nl 

 !some code 1
    
if (x0<=0.0) 
break
end
 
 !some code 2     

end

Comment: @Koka This looks like an if-then-else-statement. The GOTO jumps over a part of the code which would be executed if `x0 > 0.0`. so you could write: `DO Ic =1,Nl; ! some code; IF (x0 > 0.0) then ! SOME CODE 2; END IF; ! SOME CODE 3; END DO`. And if `SOME CODE 3` does not exist, you can just replace the goto with `CONTINUE` as you restart the loop.

Comment: @Kvantour thank you again. Your comments have been really helpful.